# Distribution of waiting time conditioned on a fixed time length

Tags: pr.probability, probability-distributions, queueing-theory

**FYI**, this question is a duplicate from [math stack exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4802739/distribution-of-waiting-time-conditioned-on-a-fixed-time-length)
I ask here again because I got no response.

Suppose, I work in a factory production line. The time for me to finish wrapping product $A$ (or $B$) is exponentially distributed with parameter $\lambda_1$ (or $\lambda_2$), i.e., $X\sim\exp(\lambda_1)$, $Y\sim\exp(\lambda_2)$. My routine is to take turns wrapping product $A$ and $B$. I start with $A$, which takes $X_1$ time, then $B$, which takes $Y_1$ time, and so on. When I finish wrapping $A$, no time is lapsed before I start wrapping $B$. When my legal daily working hour $T$ is reached, I stop working immediately. I am interested in how many $A$ and $B$ I have wrapped during this $T$ time period. I want to know the distribution of numbers of product $A$ or $B$, expectation and variance. Also I want to know the conditioning on $T$, the distribution of time $X_1$, $X_2$ and so on.

Let $$f_X(x)=\lambda_1\exp(-\lambda_1x)$$
$$f_Y(y)=\lambda_2\exp(-\lambda_2y)$$
Let $N(A)$ (or $N(B)$) to represent the number of product $A$ (or $B$) I have wrapped during the time period $T$. Then,
$$P(N(A)\ge n)=\int_0^T f_X\star f_Y\star \cdots\star f_X(x) dx$$
where $\star$ denotes convolution and in this expression $f_X$ is convoluted $n$ times.

I am wondering is there a closed formula for this pmf and its expectation and variance. Similarly, we can work out $N(B)$. Is there a closed formula for its pmf and its expectation and variance? Conditioned on $T$, what is the distribution of $X_1$, $X_2$ and so on. I am sure there are literature results on this, kindly let me know some references as well.

Comment: exponentials belong to the chi-squared family, so you can immediately reduce your N fold convolution to a 2 fold convolution, but I don't know if you can get more explicit than that

Comment: I saw hypoexponential distribution on wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypoexponential_distribution  But again the formula is very complicated, I don't know whether there is a simpler version and whether there is a closed formula for mean and variance.

Comment: What are $T_1$ and $T_2$? I can guess what they might be, but it would be better to define them in the question.

Comment: It is a typo, I fixed it. @JukkaKohonen

Comment: What you describe seems to be an alternating renewal process. You find something about it in many books on applied probability, f.i. Asmussen (2003), Applied Probabiilty and Queues, p. 173 and the following sections.

Comment: and more specifically "alternating Poisson process" as the waiting times are both exponentially distributed.

Comment: Thanks @DieterKadelka I think those are not conditioned on a fixed time $T$. Anyway I found a relevant paper on this topic. http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.spl.2015.08.006